# how to set the system $PATH outside of users .bash_profile on OSX for an added PHP version you installed

Tags: php, macos, path, system, osx-leopard

Ok so here is my problem. I am trying to write a php script that will run the following type of command.

```
exec("$(which php) -f /path/to/script.php >> /path/to/log.log 2>&1 &");
```

The problem is, I am running OSX 10.5 leopard and using the Entropy PHP package. This creates php under /usr/local/php5/bin. The normal php that is installed with OSX in under /usr/bin. So when PHP executes this command it is using the wrong PHP executable. Now I know how to change the $PATH in my .bash_profile by adding it to the begining of the $PATH so that the system takes the PHP I want other then the default PHP. The problem is, when running the php from a script it doesn't do it under my user. So then it doesn't have the updated $PATH settings.

I have also looked into setting it in /etc/paths and etc/paths.d/ but these both append the path to the end, I need it to append to the beginning so that my script will use the right PHP executable.

I know I probably could run another exec command and set the path but this is only a local environment issue and when the code goes to production I won't need this set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to set the global path for all users. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x) for a few examples.

For example, if the user running the command is using `bash` as its shell you may edit /etc/bashrc  adding a line like:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/more/paths:/
```

Another option is to modify /etc/launchd.conf (note that it does not exist on Leopard by default and expects `csh` `setenv` syntax)

Comment: I found that and that is where I figured most of my stuff out from. The problem is it those solutions append to the path, I need to prepend

Comment: I might look into the other methods other then the /etc/paths and paths.d solution but that seemed a little much. I don't think I can do it to the users bash, its the _www user executing the script from PHP.

Comment: Ok I think setting /etc/bashrc is the way to go, it did set it globally but PHP when doing the exec command is still going to /usr/bin/php Is it not user bash?

Comment: It worked right after restarting, I think I could of just sourced the file though?

Comment: No you could not source the file. That would affect only the current shell and not the one started by the user running the php command.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried executing this before your exec function:

```
$my_new_path = '/usr/local/php5/bin';
putenv( "PATH=" . $my_new_path . PATH_SEPARATOR . getenv('PATH') );

//then run your exec() call
```

Comment: You must of started writing that after I updated my question. I don't want to do this in the code because there isn't a need for it on the production side and the paths are different. I could do this temporarily but seems like a pain and there should be a way to change this.

Comment: I did, yes. You might also want to consider running a VM that's very similar to production to eliminate some of the configuration inconsistencies. IMHO, to be as deterministic as possible, if it's not in the source code (under source control), it should be identical. If you strive to have that as a procedure, there are less "oh no! it's broken on production!" events. HTH

Answer (score 0):

IF i were you i would make a wrapper script specifically for exec and shell invocation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php 

include('/path/to/script.php');
```

This way you can use the environment variable that points to php, which will work on the majority of nix systems.

Now that still doesnt get you set right on your OS X install for that you are going to have hardcode the path or follow the answer nimrodm linked to.